# Por qué la validación de mi formulario no funciona en github pages?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const nombre = document.querySelector('#nombre')
const correo = document.querySelector('#correo')
const mensaje = document.querySelector('#mensaje')
const formulario = document.querySelector('#form')
const btnEnviar = document.querySelector('#enviarForm')

const datosForm = {
  nombre: '',
  correo: '',
  mensaje: ''
}


nombre.addEventListener('input', leerDatos)
correo.addEventListener('input', leerDatos)
mensaje.addEventListener('input', leerDatos)

btnEnviar.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  const {
    nombre,
    correo,
    mensaje
  } = datosForm

  if (nombre === '' || correo === '' || mensaje === '') {
    mostrarAlerta('Todos los campos son obligatorios.', true)
    return;
  }

  mostrarAlerta('El formulario ha sido enviado. ')
})

//lee lo que se ingresa al input   
function leerDatos(e) {
  datosForm[e.target.id] = e.target.value
}

function mostrarAlerta(mensajeAlerta, error = false) {
  const alerta = document.createElement('P')
  alerta.textContent = mensajeAlerta

  if (error) {
    alerta.classList.add('error')
  } else {
    alerta.classList.add('correcto')
  }

  formulario.appendChild(alerta)

  setTimeout(() => {
    alerta.remove()
  }, 5000)
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container" id="contact">
    <div class="form-area g-3" id="form" data-aos="fade-zoom-in" data-aos-easing="ease-in-back" data-aos-delay="300" data-aos-offset="0">
      <div class="row single-form g-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
          <h1 class="mb-4"><b>Contactáme</b></h1>
          <div class="left d-flex">
            <img class="social_icon" src="/img/email_icon.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="mt-2 mb-4">josm_reyesp@unicah.edu</p>
          </div>

          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/miguelito.reyes.712/" target="_blank"><img class="social_icon" src="/img/fb_icon.png" alt=""></a>
          <a href="https://instagram.com/jose.miguel28_" target="_blank"><img class="social_icon" src="/img/ig_icon.png" alt=""></a>
          <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=50488642297&text=Hola%21%20Quisiera%20%20saber%20sobre%20tus%20servicios." target="_blank"><img class="social_icon" src="/img/whatsapp_icon.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 g-3">
          <div class="right">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="nombre" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Tu Nombre">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="correo" class="form-label">Correo</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="correo" placeholder="Tu Correo">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="mensaje" class="form-label">Mensaje</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="mensaje" rows="3" placeholder="Escribe un mensaje"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="enviarForm">Enviar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

soy relativamente nuevo en esto del desarrollo web, la cuestión es que tengo una validación para un formulario, si lo pruebo de manera local, todo bien, tengo el proyecto alojado en githubPages, y cuando intento “probar” desde allí, no me funciona la validación, adjunto el código del proyecto y también el link de github pages: https://josemiguel28.github.io/github-pages-portfolio/

Comment: La ruta ./js/main.js donde guardas tu script no existe, o eso me manda github pague al intentar acceder a ella.

Comment: Intenta moverlo a la carpeta public a ver que tal

Comment: ya lo intente pero sigue sin funcionar :/

Comment: Oye, es raro. Gihub page a veces tarda en cargar la pagina en el servidor cuando la modificas, ¿esperaste lo suficiente?(el mismo te enseña que ya hizo el vambio poniendo en verde la pagina)

Comment: Intenta declarar la carpeta js como publica en el servidor que estas usando